# What to do with pushed in tile?

Tags: tile

I need to fix this slightly pushed in tile and get it looking normal again. Can anybody advise on what I should do, e.g. what to buy and general instructions/technique? I'm worried that it's going to fall through! [image: First], [image: second] and [image: third]. Thanks!

Comment: This is probably a sign that the wall is rotted.  Does the wall flex much or feel spongy if you press against it?

Comment: Thanks for the input, Steven. I have replied to this (and the others) on the answer I accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Steven mentions in comments you could have rot in the wall.  I wouldn't say this is the case but it is definitely a possibility.

You need to take the tile out.  Get a putty knife or something comparable and chisel out the grout.  Try to pry it off.  If that doesn't work then get a wood block and tap the crap out of the block on top of the tile with a hammer.  Every 20 or so taps test tile to see if it is loose.  You should give pretty firm taps.  The tile will come loose this way or push into the wall if wall is wet.

From there you have to either fix the wall issue and reinstall or just reinstall with more material.  You might need a little thinset for it to be pushed out or layering mastic on mastic.

Comment: Something definitely must have happened for the tile to move like that.  Is this tile inside a bath/shower area or on a wall?

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. I have checked the tiles a couple away from it and it's solid as a rock. However, out of paranoia, I never checked the ones immediately next to it. My main worry is that the wall is rot as you said now, because when you look into the "gap" (i.e. the bit where the tile is pushed in), it's totally dark and I would have expected to see the plaster board or something, right?

Comment: Do you have any access from the other side of this wall?

Comment: No, it's the public hallway/stairs on the other side of the wall (I live in an apartment block).